# How to separate MVVM

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, mvvm, castle-windsor

I want to set up my project with the MVVM pattern with C#.

So I want to have three projects in my solution:

- `[projectname].Model`
- `[projectname].View`
- `[projectname].ViewModel`

I've found something like hey I separate my stuff but its all in one project. So there is in my opinion no real separation.

So I come to the Castle Windsor microkernel.

Now I want something like `[projectname].Loader` which loads my model, my ViewModels and views and starts the application.

But I can't figure out how to do this. How could I set the `DataContext` of my view to the ViewModel?

ViewModels would get a constructor injection for the model.

Comment: I think you are mixing separation of concerns and logical separation. The fact that things are all in the same assembly or solution does not mean the separation of concern is not respected. It is totally fine to have everything in the same logical unit. What is important is to reduce the view model awareness of your views and keep your application modular.

Comment: in my opinion its not really seperated. For me Its cleaner if you really seperate it

Comment: From experience it is not cleaner, nor dirtier. An application module will often be composed of the 3 elements. The logical separation is only defined by the function of your module, not the MVVM pattern.

Comment: Agreed with @Ucodia. The MVVM design pattern has nothing to do with how few or many assemblies you have or what is where. There are valid reasons to have your viewmodels and views in another assembly, but it's entirely reasonable not to do it, either.

Comment: You should read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx and download (and fully understand) the project in the code sample since it's a fully functional MVVM example.  It sounds like you might be missing some of the foundational knowledge that you need to implement this pattern in the intended way.

Comment: FWIW, you may also want to check out Caliburn Micro if you're working with WPF/Silverlight.

Comment: @Schadstoff Why is it cleaner? Your sense of aesthetic is not a good reason. I'm not sure that you actually understand the MVVM pattern and agree with Quanta's advice.

Comment: @Dave Hillier, Quanta You are right. I guess im on the right way now.
(at) Phil Degenhardt I'll give it a look later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try taking a look at [Prism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg406140.aspx), particularly the [section on Dependency Injection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921140%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx).  It allows you to keep your [projectname].Model, [projectname].View and [projectname].ViewModel assemblies truly independent of each other.

Answer (score 0):

yes I agree with first ans because Prism is more flexibly compare of MVVM so it allows you to keep your prejectName.Model , ProjectName.View and ProjectName.ViewModel accesible as well as MVVM

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to Prism, you could take a look at Caliburn Micro. You can combine that with Windsor if you like.

Kind regards,
Marwijn